# Error (cross-origin) getElementsByTagName in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am try to get input value, in an iframe. 
I am already researched some similar problems in this web side. But I always take following errors.

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost adres" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

My Code:

```
var x=document.getElementById('frameName')
var y=x.contentWindow
y.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

and then I take that error.

How can fix that problem . Thx

SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost adres" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: What's the URL of the iframe vs your site?  If they don't match, then you can't talk to the iframe like this; security reasons.  If they are on different domains, but you own both, then you can try using `postMessage` to communicate.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: i don't think you can "fix" this "problem" without reworking and controlling each page.